# Unable to run calico ingress and egress rules

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I have been trying to experiment with the calico network rules and I'm finding it tough to get the ingress and the egress rules to work with `order` in calico after denying all ingress and egress rules.

```
 kubectl get pods --show-labels
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
hello-web3   1/1     Running   0          45m   app=foo
hello-web4   1/1     Running   0          45m   app=bar
hello-web5   1/1     Running   0          15s   app=foobar
hello-web6   1/1     Running   0          4s    app=barbar
```

My network policy is as follows

```
---
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ppdp-default
spec:
  selector: all()
  order: 2000
  types:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
---
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ppdp-egress-trusted
spec:
  selector: app == 'foo'
  order: 1000
  types:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - action: Allow
    destination:
      selector: app == 'bar'
---
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ppdp-ingress-trusted
spec:
  selector: app == 'foobar'
  order: 100
  types:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - action: Allow
    source:
      selector: app == 'barbar'
```

Output for Ingress:

```
(base) ➜ ✗ kubectl exec --stdin --tty hello-web5 -- sh
/ # ^C
/ # wget -qO- --timeout=2 http://hello-web6:8080
^C
/ # wget -qO- --timeout=2 http://hello-web6:8080
wget: bad address 'hello-web6:8080'
/ # command terminated with exit code 1
---
(base) ➜ ✗ kubectl exec --stdin --tty hello-web6 -- sh
/ # wget -qO- --timeout=2 http://hello-web5:8080
wget: bad address 'hello-web5:8080'
/ # command terminated with exit code 1
```

Output for Egress

```
(base) ➜ ✗ kubectl exec --stdin --tty hello-web3 -- sh
/ # wget -qO- --timeout=2 http://hello-web4:8080
^C
/ # command terminated with exit code 130
```

Am I missing anything? Any help would be of great use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you mention that you have problems with order, can I assume that without specifying the order the network policies work fine?

Comment: No, its not working then i want to know how to define and give the order to them

Comment: Sure, what namespaces your pod are running? Can you describe your goal with this network policy? It might be easier that way for me to reproduce this.

Comment: in a namespace, I want to deny traffic among all pods in the first place and then allow egress or ingress traffic between specific pods (matching labels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **In a namespace, I want to deny traffic among all pods in the first place and then allow egress or ingress traffic between specific pods
> (matching labels)**

While I don't know why you're using the order or calico network policies the goal described in the comments can be achieved with Kubernetes network policies supported by Calico CNI. I prepared a simple example of how network policies work with those. So let's start with a list of pods that I have created in `dev` namespace:

```sh
➜  ~ kgp -n dev --show-labels -owide

NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES   LABELS
centos        1/1     Running   0          30m   10.244.120.68   minikube   <none>           <none>            host=centos
echo-server   1/1     Running   0          30m   10.244.120.69   minikube   <none>           <none>            host=echo-server
```

Notice the labels. In my example we are going to allow ingress traffic to `echo-server` from host named `centos`. Let's first test if the connections works between those:

```
[root@centos /]# curl 10.244.120.69:80 -v
* About to connect() to 10.244.120.69 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.244.120.69...
* Connected to 10.244.120.69 (10.244.120.69) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 10.244.120.69
> Accept: */*
  "path": "/",
  "headers": {
    "user-agent": "curl/7.29.0",
    "host": "10.244.120.69",
    "accept": "*/*"
  "os": {
    "hostname": "echo-server"
  },
  "connection": {}
* Connection #0 to host 10.244.120.69 left intact
```

Now let's deny all traffic in that namespace:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all
  namespace: dev
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

Once this policy is in place previous test fails:

```yaml
➜  ~ keti -n dev centos bash 
[root@centos /]# curl 10.244.120.69:80 -v
* About to connect() to 10.244.120.69 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.244.120.69...
* Connection timed out
* Failed connect to 10.244.120.69:80; Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.244.120.69:80; Connection timed out
```

Let's now apply the ingress policy that will allow us to reach the `echo-server`. So basically we selects the pod's label that we want the policy to be applied to and the choose which pod ingress traffic is allowed from:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-echo
  namespace: dev    
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      host: echo-server
  ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            host: centos
```

Now since we allowed the traffic towards our `echo-server`, we might feel tempted to test this straight away but this still won't work. While we allowed the ingress traffic toward `echo-server` we have to remember that we denied both `ingress` and `egress` in our `deny-all` policy. This means that we have to allow the `egress` traffic from `centos` pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: egress-centos
  namespace: dev    
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      host: centos
  egress:
    - to:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            host: echo-server
```

After that we have successfully allowed traffic for some specific pods in the same namespace while deny every pod that don't match the labels.

Comment: Then why is it that in this link https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/tutorials/kubernetes-policy-demo/kubernetes-demo they allowed only ingress traffic ??

Comment: This is happening because isolation policy there does not have any Ingress/Egress type specified and by default. If no `policyTypes` are specified on a `NetworkPolicy` then by default **Ingress will always be set** and Egress will be set if the NetworkPolicy has any egress rules. This is described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource) under `PolicyTypes`. I provide the example above to match exactly scenario that you described, meaning that you want to control both ingress and egress.